# Resta entre dos input y mostrar resultado en otro sin necesidad de un botón con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos input `txtrecibido` y `txtcambio`. Quiero hacer que al poner la cantidad de dinero que pago el cliente en recibido y este se reste sin modificar el total, pero que el resultado se muestre en cambio así sabrá cuanto debe devolver al cliente.

quiero que esto se realice sin necesidad de un botón por favor ayudarme con esto estaré eternamente agradecido soy nuevo y tengo está asignación y he intentado pero no he podido.
Estos es lo que he intentado pero no he logrado nada.

```
<div class="form-group float-right ">
                                        <div class="form-group col">
                                            <div class="input-group col-md-9  ">
                                                <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="txtrecibido" placeholder="RECIBIDO" style="font-weight: bold; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;" disabled >
                                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><i class="mdi mdi-currency-usd"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                              
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col">
                                            <div class="input-group col-md-9 ">
                                                <input  type="number"  id="txtcambio" class="form-control" placeholder="CAMBIO" style="font-weight: bold; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;" >
                                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><i class="mdi mdi-cached" ></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

```
<script>
function DarCambio(){

    valor = parseInt(valor);
    cambio = document.getElementById("txtrecibido").innerHTML;
    total = document.getElementById("txtrecibido").innerHTML; 

    document.getElementById('txtcambio').innerHTML = cambio - total;

}

function Cambio() {
    var txtrecibido = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtrecibido").val);
    var txttotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("txttotal").val);

    document.getElementById("txtcambio").innerHTML = txtrecibido - txttotal

}
```

Comment: Hola, indica por favor algo de código de lo que has intentado hacer. Dices que utilizas ASP.NET MVC 5, podrías indicar el código de la Vista el Modelo y el Controlador.

Comment: Saludos Rafael los que he encontrado han sido con botones tube que eliminar los códigos por eso pido ayuda como lo harías sin necesidad de utilizar un botón ya que no lo quiero con un botón quiero que se haga automáticamente como lo harías tendiendo tres input txtrecibido, txtcambio el cual es donde quiero mostrar el resultado y txttotal que es el que se utilizará para hacer la operación ya que ese campo se llenará automáticamente al agregar un producto a la tabla de orden nose si entiendes ejemplo: el cliente quiere un taladro cuesta 200 ese total está en el txttotal o la el total

Comment: Te podemos brindar apoyo pero te recomiendo para evitar te cierren la pregunta agregues lo que lleves aunque este incompleto o tenga errores, checa [ask]

Comment: Ya he actualizado con lo que tenía soy nuevo solo quiero que alguien me ayude con esto si es posible por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que tienes una etiqueta de **JavaScript** en tu pregunta te propongo una solución de este modo:

- Tienes un primer `input` donde se ingresa cuanto cuesta el producto y este mismo se obtiene a través de su `id` y se asigna a una variable
- Capturas el evento `change()` del segundo `input` que es donde se escribe por ejemplo con cuanto esta pagando el cliente y se asigna a una variable
- Obtienes el tercer `input` que es donde se asignará el valor que resultó de la resta
- Dentro de la función anónima del listener del segundo `input` declaramos que la variable del input 3 va a contener la resta del: *precio2 menos el precio1*

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    El producto cuesta: <input type="text" id="caja1" placeholder="Precio 1">
    <br><br>
    Estas pagando con: <input type="text" id="caja2" placeholder="Precio 2">
    <br><br>
    Tu cambio es : <input type="text" id="caja3" placeholder="Precio 3">
    <div id="aviso"></div>
    <script>
        let precio1 = document.getElementById("caja1")
        let precio2 = document.getElementById("caja2")
        let precio3 = document.getElementById("caja3")
        
        precio2.addEventListener("change", () => {
            precio3.value = parseFloat(precio2.value) - parseFloat(precio1.value)

        })
        
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Lo hice tal cual y no me funciona nose porque cuando pongo el valor con el que paga el cliente no hace nada

Comment: ¿@JuanMartínReyesPachano en que parte estas colocando el script?, además ¿está s usando algún otro id para identificar a los inputs?

Comment: Donde mismo pongo mis demás script nose porque no me hace nada hice el ejemplo así como lo pusiste cree tres input tal cuales para hacer la prueba y nada ahora te dejo los codigo

Comment: ¿colocaste primero el html y al final el script @JuanMartínReyesPachano?, abre la consola con F12 y en la pasteña de consola revisa si da errores

Comment: <input type="text" id="txttotal" placeholder="txttotal" >
 <input type="text" id="txtrecibido" placeholder="txtrecibido" >
 <input type="text" id="txtcambio" placeholder="txtcambio" >
                              
<script>
     debugger;
     let total = document.getElementById("txttotal")
     let txtrecibido = document.getElementById("txtrecibido")
     let txtcambio = document.getElementById("txtcambio")
     txtrecibido.addEventListener("change", () => {
         txtcambio.val = parseFloat(txtrecibido.val) - parseFloat(total.val)
     })
</script>

Comment: @JuanMartínReyesPachano me parece tienes un error, ya que la propiedad en JS que se lee para modificar el valor de un input es **value** y tu pusiste val

Comment: No me sale nada nose porque puse un debugger pero solo cuando refresco es que me sale luego como que no funciona el script o como que no entra al script y hace la función

Comment: No le salía en el inteligent la propiedad value solo val la cambie a value y sigue igual nose que pasa

Comment: una pregunta para usar el total en un label como lo haría ? Si el total lo traigo de un método @Model.Total cómo hago para hagarrar ese valor desde un label ? Y seguir utilizando los dos input de txtrecibido  y txtcambio?

Comment: cómo podría hacerlo así ya que el input se ve un poco fuera de diseño se ve más suave un label como puedo asignarle el valor total para poder hacer la operación  ?